# Webmin install?

Tags: 14.04, webmin

I am trying to install Webmin, on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, I have gotten as far as having webmin showing up in software center but when I click install I get the error message "This requires installing packages from unauthenticated sources".  I have googled that message and have tried about four different solutions but they don't seem to help the problem. Does any one else have any other solutions?

Comment: @Vembu, I ran sudo vi /etc/apt/sources.list and pressed I on the keyboard but when I try to press the down arrow key the characters change to either A or B or some of the text becomes highlighted and is deleted. Am I doing this right? –  Josh1

Comment: Change 'vi' to 'gedit' and run the command again. I don't know why the answerer suggested you use vi.

Comment: @Seth In general GUI applications will not play nice with sudo under X.  For this case, nano would be safest to use in line with sudo in lieu of gedit.  Invocation of gedit is best done with pkexec to do what you're proposing.

Comment: @StephenMichaelKellat Oh,  yes,  quite right. I can't believe I suggested that. Guess I had synapse lapse ;P

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your issue please follow the below steps and check.

1. Run below command to edit the source file:

   ```
   sudo vi /etc/apt/sources.list
   ```
2. Press i on keyboard to start editing the file and add this line into the end:

   ```
   deb http://download.webmin.com/download/repository saucy contrib
   ```

   Press Esc to exit edit. Shift + : and followed by wq to save the changes.
3. Now execute command to download and install the key:

   ```
   wget -q http://www.webmin.com/jcameron-key.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -
   ```
4. After that, you can always use below commands to install the latest version of Webmin:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install webmin
   ```

   Finally in your client’s web browser go to the webmin login page and check

Comment: sarge ... I doubt that. I changed it to "saucy".

Comment: Read the comment on the question. Suggesting people use vi isn't very helpful.